# Get dates Queries with arel and gt lt between methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, arel

I want to get dates **greater** than one specific date,or **smaller** than that or even dates **between** two given dates with **arel**.this is my controller:

```
@from_time = search[:value][:from_time]
@to_time = search[:value][:to_time]
letters_query = letters[@key].between(@from_time..@to_time)
@letters = Letter.joins(:official).where(letters_query)
```

and this is the **json** I pass into my controller

```
 Parameters: {"query"=>{"search"=>{"0"=>{"key"=>"letter_date", "value"=>{"from_time"=>"01/09/1395", "to_time"=>"30/09/1395"}, "type"=>"date"}}}}
```

I'm sure about getting the parameters, to be noted my dates are solar kind!
it returns this **error**:

```
 If you are passing user input to a predicate, you must either give an appropriate type caster object to the `Arel::Table`, or manually cast the value before passing it to Arel.
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a column to `quote` has been deprecated. It is only used for type casting, which should be handled elsewhere. See https://github.com/rails/arel/commit/6160bfbda1d1781c3b08a33ec4955f170e95be11 for more information. (called from p at /home/afsane/Desktop/Afsane Development/Production/isecretariat/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:511)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: table_exists? is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use #data_source_exists? instead) (called from p at /home/afsane/Desktop/Afsane Development/Production/isecretariat/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:511)
    Arel performing automatic type casting is deprecated, and will be removed in Arel 8.0. If you are seeing this, it is because you are manually passing a value to an Arel predicate, and the `Arel::Table` object was constructed manually. The easiest way to remove this warning is to use an `Arel::Table` object returned from calling `arel_table` on an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.

    If you're certain the value is already of the right type, change `attribute.eq(value)` to `attribute.eq(Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(value))` (you will be able to remove that in Arel 8.0, it is only required to silence this deprecation warning).

    You can also silence this warning globally by setting `$arel_silence_type_casting_deprecation` to `true`. (Do NOT do this if you are a library author)

    If you are passing user input to a predicate, you must either give an appropriate type caster object to the `Arel::Table`, or manually cast the value before passing it to Arel.
```

for greated and smaller I used this:

```
letters_query = officials[@key].lt(@to_time)
letters_query = officials[@key].gt(@from_time)
```

I tested this alot and all the problem is with this **line**:

```
@letters = Letter.joins(:official).where(letters_query)
```

any ideas?

Comment: what is `letters[@key]`?

Comment: Key is the column name for example letters[:created_at]@JagdeepSingh

Comment: I find out the problem the query should look like this:  letters[:letter_date].gt(Date.new(2016,10,20)) but the problem is my dates are solar not christian calendar! What should I do ?

Comment: this link helps a lot but as I said just for christian calendar : https://www.calebwoods.com/2015/08/11/advanced-arel-cheat-sheet/

Comment: When you query dates that are smaller or greater than a specific other dates, than that is the same as find all dates that are different from the specific other date. Is that really want you want?

Comment: Can you use this: https://github.com/hzamani/parsi-date? If this is about the same calendar as you are using, then you can parse the date params before doing query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With arel, this is how to generate a suitable query for the dates:

```
letters = Letter.arel_table
@letter = Letter.where(letters[:date].between(Date.new(2016,08,24)..Date.new(2016,09,24))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [parsi-date](https://github.com/hzamani/parsi-date) here as the years in the gem and your question seem similar to me. You will need to parse your query params accordingly. You will do `to_gregorian` if the date stored in your db is in christian calendar format.

```
@from_time = Parsi::Date.parse(search[:value][:from_time]).to_gregorian
@to_time = Parsi::Date.parse(search[:value][:to_time]).to_gregorian
```